# Netbeans build failure

Tags: maven, netbeans, glassfish

Brand new to netbeans and working on the address-book tutorial. I am able to run the program without issues but when I build I get the following error. I have yet to find any possible solutions to the issue

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.4:redeploy (deploy) on project address-book: Execution deploy of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.4:redeploy failed: Failed to create deployer with implementation class org.codehaus.cargo.container.glassfish.GlassFish4xInstalledLocalDeployer for the parameters (container [id = [glassfish4x]], deployer type [installed]). InvocationTargetException: The container configuration directory "c://glassfish4/glassfish/domains" does not exist. Please configure the container before attempting to perform any local deployment. Read more on: http://cargo.codehaus.org/Local+Configuration -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 13):

How does Maven know which server to deploy to and where is it located?

It's all in the `pom.xml` file.

Sometimes you will have to trace up the parents of the `pom.xml` to find it.

In the case of Java EE tutorial, when I was building project `hello1`, Maven couldn't find the location of my GlassFish server.

I traced up the parents of `pom.xml` to find
`C:\mine\tools_installation\glassfish4\docs\javaee-tutorial\examples\pom.xml(51):

<glassfish.home.prefix>c:/</glassfish.home.prefix>`
Then I changed it to
`<glassfish.home.prefix>c:/mine/tools_installation</glassfish.home.prefix>`.

Answer (score 0):

The container configuration directory "c://glassfish4/glassfish/domains" does not exist.

Maven / Cargo looks for a folder defined in pom.xml and it doesn't exist on your computer.

I the property you need to change is  and you'll need to set it to your GlassFish installation directory.

Comment: those double // in 'C://...' looks a little suspect i think you can get away with just one, but just a guess. what's actually in pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

So it is automatically taken from the parent `examples` folder `pom.xml` rather than from your open example. So you should edit the `pom.xml` from

```
YOUR_GLASSFISH_HOME\docs\javaee-tutorial\examples
```

It think it is a bug in the examples `pom.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar error, the solution is very simple You need to edit the pom.xml file as follows. Replace line 38:
${glassfish.home.prefix}/glassfish4
to your GlassFish home, I run GlassFish 4.1.1 installed in C:\ drive. So my modification is:
${glassfish.home.prefix}glassfish-4.1.1.

Please note the slash before glassfish was removed too. The slash after c: in line 51 suffice. 
Build it again. Should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error adding in pom.xml those lines:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>windows</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <glassfish.home>C://Program Files//glassfish-4.1.1</glassfish.home>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I hope this help

Comment: Your solution for the user's example is patchwork because you don't fix the parent `pom.xml` file. Instead of adding these lines to the subfolder's `pom.xml` try to just replace the `glassfish.home` tag value by `glassfish-4.1.1`. For the tutorial's example, it's usually in a directory like this `glassfish-4.1.1\docs\javaee-tutorial\examples`.

Answer (score 0):

I also usually install my glassfish development server under c:/opt so I had the same problem with the hello2 tutorial from the *Java Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE) 8 Tutorial*.

To solve this problem, I changed the *"tutorial-examples/pom.xml"* file which is the root parent of all the tutorial POM files. As I am using the J2EE8 tutorial, it is expected that glassfish5 is installed so this is reflected in the **properties** section:

```
<glassfish.home>${glassfish.home.prefix}/glassfish5</glassfish.home>
```

I not sure what tutorial version you are going through but as I see, it expects a glassfish 4 installation thus you need to edit the POM file accordingly.

Also (in the J2EE 8 tutorial), ${glassfish.home.prefix} is defined for every supported profile. For windows the windows profile, I had to change the line:

```
<glassfish.home.prefix>c:/</glassfish.home.prefix>
```

to

```
<glassfish.home.prefix>c:/opt</glassfish.home.prefix>
```

So the complete windows profile will be:

```
<profile>
        <id>windows</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <glassfish.home.prefix>c:/opt</glassfish.home.prefix>
            <glassfish.executables.suffix>.bat</glassfish.executables.suffix>
        </properties>
</profile>
```

Of course, you'll have to edit the POM file accordingly to your own setup.